# How to avoid repeating yourself when using generics or advanced java features

Tags: java, generics, solid-principles

There are multiple methods that do exactly the same, but their parameter is different but have few similar fields.
The method acts only on those similar fields.

```
public static List<TypeAItem> filterProcessableItems(List<TypeAItem> items) {

    return items.stream().map(item -> {

                if (isNull(item.getDate1())) {

                    log.error("Date1 is null {}", item);

                    return null;

                }

                if (isNull(item.getDate2())) {

                    log.error("Date2 is null {}", item);

                    return null;

                }

                if (isNull(item.getPrice1())) {

                    log.error("price1 is null {}", item);

                    return null;

                }

                return item;                }).filter(Objects::nonNull).toList();  
}

 

public static List<TypeBItem> filterProcessableItems(List<TypeBItem> items) {

    return items.stream().map(item -> {

                if (isNull(item.getDate1())) {

                    log.error("Date1 is null {}", item);

                    return null;

                }

                if (isNull(item.getDate2())) {

                    log.error("Date2 is null {}", item);

                    return null;

                }

                if (isNull(item.getPrice1())) {

                    log.error("price1 is null {}", item);

                    return null;

                }
                return item;}).filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .toList();
}
 
class typeAItem extends GeneralItem {
    private LocalDate date1;
    private LocalDate date2;
    private int price1;
    private int price2;
    // many more fields
}

class typeBItem extends GeneralItem {
    private LocalDate date1;
    private LocalDate date2;
    private int price1;
    private int price2;
    // many more fields
}
```

How is ot possible to implement such a functionality - only one method that handles this logic.

There are 2 solutions that should not be used:

1. Move the fields to the parent class GeneralItem
2. Multiple if blocks that checks instanceof and casts.

Are there advanced java features/ techniques that allow to do that?

Comment: It depends on what you want exactly. For example, is the log statement containing the field name important? That'll limit some options. You should make the question clear by specifying exactly what you need.

Comment: @Jorn yes the log is important. I'm expecting the same behavior, but without repeating the code. I'm not sure it's even possible with my 2 requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should definitely moved shared properties into the Parent class.

Next, I see what you're trying to achieve is getting a filtered list of items where all properties involved are non-null. You can achieve this with Java streams:

```
public static List<GeneralItem> filterProcessableItems(List<GeneralItem> items) {
  return items.stream()
      .filter(i -> isNonNull(i.getDate1()) && isNonNull(i.getDate2()) && isNonNull(i.getPrice1()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**EDIT**

If changing the parent class is not possible (maybe it's a 3rd party dependency that you don't have access to) you have the option to create an intermediary class with those shared properties. Both TypeA and TypeB should inherit that class

```
public class MoreSpecificItem extends GeneralItem  {
    private LocalDate date1;
    private LocalDate date2;
    private int price1;
    private int price2;
}

public class typeAItem extends MoreSpecificItem {}
public class typeBItem extends MoreSpecificItem {}
```

Then for the method:

```
public static List<MoreSpecificItem> filterProcessableItems(List<MoreSpecificItem> items) { /*...*/}`
```

If the two classes don't inherit a common property/method you won't be able to treat them as the same (unless you're using reflection, which I wouldn't recommend)

Comment: What is `isNonNull`? Do you mean [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object))? Personally, I would use `i -> i.getDate1() != null && i.getDate2() != null && i.getDate3() != null)`, which is shorter and IMHO easier to read, and reserve `Objects.nonNull` only for use as `filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: But as I said, moving those fields to the parent class is not doable. The question is less about best practice, and more about java, technical. The code is modified for the question so it's less relevant